# adding classes to table headers elements when there are no classes or ids to select them directly

Tags: jquery

I have the following table

```
<table class="results">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title1</th>
    <th>Title2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to add different attributes to each `<th>`.. Ideally using jquery .index and .attr

Just not sure how to select the `<th>` when there's no id or class..

I'm guessing that we can use the .results class?

Comment: Do you want to add atrribute in all the th of table with class "results"? Please edit your question and add your desire output as well

Comment: it's a DOM tree. you don't need ids directly on something you want to manipulate. You just need a path from something that DOES have a unique/findable identifier and go from there. e.g. `//table[@class="results"]/thead/tr/th`

Comment: Can you give details of what you're trying to achieve. Even just the HTML output itself would be helpful

Comment: I want to add different attributes to the 2 th
e.g.
th class="one"
th class="two"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add different attributes to the 2 th e.g. th class="one" th class="two"

To achieve that you could use an array of the class names which map to the indexes of the `th` elements in the table. Try this:

```js
var classes = ['one', 'two'];
$('.results th').addClass(function(i) {
  return classes[i];
});
```

```css
.one {
  color: red;
}
.two {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title1</th>
      <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>h</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("th").each(function(index,ele){

        var cla = (index===0) ? "one" : "two";

        $(this).addClass(cla);

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
        .one {
            color: red;
        }
        .two {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="results">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title1</th>
    <th>Title2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("th").each(function(index,ele){
        
        var cla = (index===0) ? "one" : "two";
        
        $(this).addClass(cla);
            
    })
})
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey I didn't downvote.. just checked your solution and it works, thanks. upvoted!